# What devices are available using Playwright devices api?

Tags: playwright

Where can I find a full list of devices enabled to be used for emulation with Playwright testing

Answer (score 6):

Its not easy to find but here is [the full list](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/blob/master/packages/playwright-core/src/server/deviceDescriptorsSource.json). The list is also obtainable by logging the `devices` variable.

Example :

```
const { chromium, devices } = require('playwright');
const iPhone11Pro = devices['iPhone 11 Pro'];

(async () => {
    const browser = await chromium.launch({
      headless: false, 
    });
    const context = await browser.newContext({
        viewport: iPhone11Pro.viewport,
        userAgent: iPhone11Pro.userAgent,
    });
    const page = await context.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://apple.com');
    
    console.log(devices); // Logs all devices

    await context.close();
    await browser.close();
})();
```

Answer (score 3):

An update of the answer by @akwasiijunior

You can view the current full list of devices here:

https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/blob/master/packages/playwright-core/src/server/deviceDescriptorsSource.json

You can also view it by installing Playwright, and printing it from a test, like so:

```sh
npm install -D @playwright/test

echo "const { devices } = require('@playwright/test'); console.log(devices)" > devices.spec.js

npx playwright test devices.spec.js
```